# chemmacros: setting up \sisetup only once for all experimental environments

Tags: siunitx, chemmacros

I am using the *experimental* environment of [`chemmacros`](https://ctan.org/pkg/chemmacros) spectroscopy module. Right now I am running `\sisetup{}` for every instance of the environment and was now wondering if there is a way to circumvent calling it every single time.

In my MWE I will just use one of the settings as an example.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules=spectroscopy}

\sisetup{
    round-mode = figures
}

\begin{document}
    \num{3.456789}

    \begin{experimental}
        \sisetup{round-mode=off}
        \num{3.456789} % I use \val{}, but this is for comparison
    \end{experimental}

\end{document}
```

Basically, I would like to run `\sisetup{}` once for **all** *experimental* environments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the package `etoolbox` to automatically set `\sisetup{round-mode=off}` at the beginning of the `experimental` environment:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules=spectroscopy}

\sisetup{
    round-mode = figures
}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{experimental}{\sisetup{round-mode=off}}

\begin{document}
    \num{3.456789}

    \begin{experimental}
%        \sisetup{round-mode=off}
        \num{3.456789} % I use \val{}, but this is for comparison
    \end{experimental}

    \num{3.456789}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I was about to answer the same :)

Comment: @clemens sorry :)

Comment: @samcarter nevermind